# JQuery FadeOut Not Working Properly

Tags: jquery

Could anybody explain to me why the fade out is not working properly for the following code. When I say it doesn't work properly the image does disappear, but it doesn't fade out over a 800ms time period. however the Fade In works fine.

```
        $('.main-image').fadeOut(800);

        $('.main-image').hide();

        $('.main-image').attr('src',newUrl);  

        $('.main-image').css('margin-left','-' + divWidth+'px');    

        $('.main-image').fadeIn(800);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you call `hide()` straight after, you want code to be executed after the [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) in the complete callback, second parameter.

`$('.main-image').fadeOut(800, function() { // do stuff when fade is done });`

`fadeIn()` works fine because it is the last action.

```
$('.main-image').fadeOut(800, function() {

    // $('.main-image').hide(); // Can be removed as fadeOut will do that already

    $('.main-image')
        .attr('src',newUrl)
        .css('margin-left','-' + divWidth+'px')
        .fadeIn(800);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.hide()` before the fadeout completes. `.fadeOut()` will hide this already, no need to call hide after.

Also, one of the great things about jquery is chaining. You can simplify this tremendously as follows:

```
$('.main-image')
    .fadeOut(800)
    .attr('src',newUrl)
    .css('margin-left','-' + divWidth+'px')
    .fadeIn(800);
```

Comment: `.attr` and `.css` won't wait for the `fadeOut` to complete.